# How further subquery to get all Product_IDs from an SQL queries?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to get all the Product_ID of a Class_ID after I query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Categories WHERE Class_ID = 1

-------------tbl_Categories------------------
| Category_ID |    Class_ID    | Product_ID |
|      1      |       1        |      2     |
|      2      |       1        |      3     |
|      3      |       4        |      4     |
|      1      |       1        |      1     |
```

Which should return me 1, 2, 3.

How can I query this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean you need to select only Product_ID's?
Like that:

> select Product_ID from tbl_Categories WHERE Class_ID = 1

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Product_ID FROM tbl_Categories WHERE Class_ID = 1